# Is Brahmo Samaj still functional?

Tags: history

wiki says
"Brahmo Samaj (Bengali: ব্রাহ্ম সমাজ Bramho Shômaj) is a Hindu reform movement. It is the societal component of Brahmoism, a monotheistic reformist movement of the Hindu religion that appeared during the Bengal Renaissance. It is practised today mainly as the Adi Dharm after its eclipse in Bengal consequent to the exit of the Tattwabodini Sabha from its ranks in 1839"

Comment: Yes, they are. But they aren't as popular as they were during the nineteenth century.

Comment: This is their site: http://www.brahmosamaj.in/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with Brahmo philosophy. They don't adhere to the real Hindu philosophy and reject the Vedas. That's why after the advent of Ramakrishna Paramhansa, who realigned the people to the correct form of substantial Hinduism, the formal Brahmo society was dissolved. Individuals might still adhere, but there's no prominence. It was dissolved mainly because Hinduism is a substantial religion, with something to offer to those who adhere to it. Brahmo on the other hand was simply an aimless version of Hinduism mixed with Christian universalism.
 
 
[To the moderators]: This answer doesn't need scriptural references, so I took the liberty to place this as an answer

Comment: Brahmo samaj Rejected the vedas??

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda Obviously

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury  how can people follow a sect which rejected vedas

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda They aren't a sect actually.

Comment: This answer is mostly correct. However, Brahmo Samaj did not reject the Vedas. They rejected the caste syste, murthi puja and some other customs and traditions that were at that time thought to be part of Hinduism.

Comment: I've always thought that Raja Ram Mohan Roy rejected the Vedas. Plus I've asked a few Brahmos about Vedas and mantras, they outright spoke nonsense about it.

Comment: Brahmos only accept the formless Brahman of the Vedas and reject God with form. Thus they do not worship any of the Hindu deities. I don't know why the Brahmos spoke nonsense about the Vedas.

Comment: Plus from the info I've gotten from the few individuals, they keep Upanishads in their worship chamber, but not Vedas. Their initiation style is an absolute replica of the Western esoteric (Satanism and related) covens - where a high priest initiates the new candidate under the supervision of a guardian.

Comment: This site has references to Brahmo faith. You'll see they have A LOT in common with Abrahamic religions, mainly due to Raja Ram Mohon Roy's inclination towards the western ideology. http://www.thebrahmosamaj.net/liturgy/brahmodharma.html

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay seems like they're nonsense :)